# change dataframe to another structure according id

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My initial pandas dataframe looks as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[999,888,1,0], [988,899,2,0], [981,821,3,0],[721,789,4,1],[723,745,5,1],[444,432,6,2],[423,412,7,2],[423,455,8,2],[478,432,9,2]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'id'])

>>>df
a    b   c id
999  888 1 0
988  899 2 0
981  821 3 0
721  789 4 1
723  745 5 1
444  432 6 2
423  412 7 2
423  455 8 2
478  432 9 2
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe with the following structure:

```
0    1    2    3   4  5
999  988  888  899 1  2
721  723  789  745 4  5
444  423  432  412 6  7
```

So in fact I just want to get the first two values of each id and each column (a,b,c).
Example:
first row -> col a: 999, 988 + col b: 888, 899 + col c: 1, 2

Edit: Thanks to Correlian I use the following code:

```
size = 3


data = df.groupby('id').head(2).melt('id').sort_values(by=['id', 'variable'])['value']
out = pd.DataFrame(data.values.reshape((size, -1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute value count of `id` to get the size (number of unique id, here 3) and the smallest count (here 2 for id=1). Group by `id` and keep the first `count` row for each group using `head`.

Then, use `melt` to flat your dataframe and sort it by `id`. Finally, reshape your dataframe according the `size` variable and create a new dataframe:

```
size, count = df.value_counts('id').agg(['size', 'min'])
data = df.groupby('id').head(count).melt('id').sort_values('id')['value']
out = pd.DataFrame(data.values.reshape((size, -1)))
print(out)

# Output:
     0    1    2    3
0  999  988  888  899
1  721  723  789  745
2  444  423  432  412
```

**Update**

> I have changed my initial dataframe to 3 columns (a,b,c) see my initial question. How do I have to change your code?

```
size, count = df.value_counts('id').agg(['size', 'min'])
m = df.groupby('id').head(count).iloc[:, :-1].values
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(m.T.reshape(-1, size, count)))
print(df)

# Output:
     0    1    2    3  4  5
0  999  988  888  899  1  2
1  721  723  789  745  4  5
2  444  423  432  412  6  7
```

Comment: I have changed my initial dataframe to 3 columns (a,b,c) see my initial question. How do I have to change your code? I tried but did not succeed..

Answer (score 1):

This could be achived by the following:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("id").head(2).set_index('id').values.flatten().reshape((3,4)))
```

**Edit**

The new example would be:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("id").head(2).set_index('id').values.flatten().reshape((3,6)))[[0,1,3,4,2,5]]
```

With this method you should reorder the columns to get the output you want.

Comment: Your answer is totally correct (for two columns). However I have changed my initial dataframe to 3 columns (a,b,c) see my initial question. How do I have to change your code? I tried but did not succeed..